# Position a jQueryUI tooltip based on mouse pointer

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, position

jQueryUI Tooltip position system is based, by default, on the position of the element triggering the tooltip. I use frequently something like this, when the triggering element in small :

```
position: {
   my: 'left top',
   at: 'right+15 center'
}
```

This renders the tooltip slighlty to the right of the triggering element. You can also pick another DOM element as your reference, like this :

```
position: {
   my: 'left top',
   at: 'right+15 center',
   of: $('#otherElement')
}
```

But it does not seem you can use the current position of the mouse pointer as your reference.

Right now, I have a use case with an extremly large triggering element (it's even much larger than the page, with an horizontal scroll). I don't have any more accurate element to use as a target in "of". The least terrible thing I can do is this :

```
position: {
   my: 'center',
   at: 'center'
}
```

But that does not prevent the tooltip from appearing very far from the mouse, if the user hovers on the left or right of the element. And because of the permanent horizontal scroll, the tootlip doesn't even appear at the same spot every time, it depends on how far you've scrolled...

Is there any way to position a jQueryUI Tooltip based on the mouse cursor ? This seems like an expected feature for a tooltip widget. Did I miss something obvious ?

EDIT : one can also put an event in the "of" attribute of "position". In that case you use the position where this event triggered as a reference. Unfortunately, there is no way in a jQueryUI Tooltip to access the event that triggered it. This feature was requested 7 years ago : https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9239

Comment: You can use the event for positioning near the mouse. Example: https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#tracking and see: https://api.jqueryui.com/position/ for `of: event` *if you provide an event object, the `pageX` and `pageY` properties will be used.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `event` you can attach to is `open` for the tooltip.

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).tooltip({
    open: function(e, ui) {
      ui.tooltip.position({
        my: 'left top',
        at: 'right+15 center',
        of: e
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p><a href="#" title="That&apos;s what this widget is">Tooltips</a> can be attached to any element. When you hover the element with your mouse, the title attribute is displayed in a little box next to the element, just like a native tooltip.</p>
<p>But as it's not a native tooltip, it can be styled. Any themes built with
  <a href="http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/" title="ThemeRoller: jQuery UI&apos;s theme builder application">ThemeRoller</a> will also style tooltips accordingly.</p>
<p>Tooltips are also useful for form elements, to show some additional information in the context of each field.</p>
<p><label for="age">Your age:</label><input id="age" title="We ask for your age only for statistical purposes."></p>
<p>Hover the field to see the tooltip.</p>
```

Comment: I accept this answer because this is very likely the right way to do it in most cases. But, for anyone reading this in the future, please note that I could not make it work in my case (tooltip appears in a different position, but still very far from the mouse). This is probably because of something specific to my situation, I couldn't figure out what exactly but it may happen to you, too.

Answer (score 1):

jQueryUI Tooltips allow you to [track the mouse](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#tracking).

```
$( document ).tooltip({
  track: true
});
```

Comment: So I did miss something obvious then. :)
That's not exactly what I want, since I expect it to open near the pointer but don't move afterwards. This is still much better than the tooltip appearing on the other side of the screen, though.